# Python's stdin.readline() to Ruby/Rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am converting some Python code to Ruby for use in a Rails app.

Page1 posts some JSON data to Page2 and then Page2 contains the Python code `sys.stdin.readline()` to read the posted JSON data and then do stuff with it.

I thought the equivalent in Ruby was `gets.strip` but it's causing my server to hang.

Original Python code:

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.readline()
<manipulate contents of data>
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**Update**

For my use-case, `request.raw_post` was the appropriate equivalent.  Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: Wouldn't it be something like `STDIN.first`?

Comment: Yeah, `gets.strip` is more like `raw_input()`. Although the differences between "get a line of input" vs. "read a line from stdin" probably aren't exactly the same in the two languages, it's easy to guess the kinds of problems you might have using the wrong one (e.g., hitting a blocking `read` to fetch more data into the buffer before returning)…

Comment: Is there any other method I might need to add? STDIN.first is causing the same hang